# Recieve zip file from Box View API

Tags: node.js, zip, box-view-api

i'm using the [Box View API](https://box-view.readme.io/reference) to convert a PDF file to HTML, i'm using the /documents/{id}/content.{extension} section.

The response for this GET call is a .zip file, however i don't know how to retrive it and make downloadable.

Also note that i'm using node.js.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own webhook URL that will be called by Box when your document status changes (one POST on your webhook for "document.viewable", and one for "document.done" plus one "document.error" if an transformation error occured).

Just listen to the "document.done" status and download the assets then. Format that is posted to the webhook you have set looks like :

```
[{
    "type": "document.done",
    "data": {
        "id": "4cca28f1159c4f368193d5014fabc16e"
    },
    "triggered_at": "2014-01-30T20:33:04.798Z"
}]
```

Beware of the docs and check the format programatically. Their API docs are often **no quite correct** and they post multiple webhooks at the time i'm writing (which is a bug i've reported).

For more info and [Box View API docs](https://box-content.readme.io/docs/view-api-webhooks%20Box%20View%20API%20docs)